# How to Display Chart.js line-chart from a MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, charts, chart.js, linechart

I have a project which requires to display a [line-chart](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html) using Chart.JS based on SQL Data loaded from Controller to the view page.

I want a simple line chart with multiple Dataset. The Dataset will have to update automatically the controller data load.

However, I tried to load data from the view to the chart, unfortunately, no luck, still getting the outcome that is not accurate.

What I want is that Every `TagsN` should have their own lines and data. but in my current result, only one line is showing. And I don't know how to do that.

`@Html.Raw(TagsC)`; `@Html.Raw(TagsN)`; `@Html.Raw(TagsD)` results are displayed on the Excell Spreadsheet.

First I convert controller Data to `Newtownsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to get the JSON format and parse it to the Chart Labels and Data.

The result might not be the same as the picture below, But I just want to see something working.

[Running Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/opcd1g8w/4/)

---

**These are test data**

**Current Code:**
*DisplayPage.cshtml*

```js
var TagsC = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model._CountedList.Select(x => x.Counted).ToList());
var TagsN = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model._NameList.Select(x => x.Tag_name).ToList());
var TagsD = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model._DateList.Select(x => x.Tag_date).ToList());
```

**Javascript**

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["06 Oct", "06 Oct", "07 Oct", "08 Oct", "08 Oct", "09 Oct", "12 Oct", "12 Oct", "12 Oct", "13 Oct", "13 Oct", "14 Oct"], // DateTime
    datasets: [{
      data: @Html.Raw(TagsC),
      label: @Html.Raw(TagsN),
      borderColor: "#3e95cd",
      fill: false
    }]
  }
});
```

**SQL Data look: (auto variating)**

[image: ![enter image description here]

> **I want a result like this:**

[image]

Everybody's help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `the wrong outcome` - What the outcome you get? How the `@Html.Raw(TagsC)` and `@Html.Raw(TagsN)` look like in runtime (you can see it in your browser when you run the app)

Comment: @MoshFeu I have updated my question with more details to help you to understand.

Comment: Thanks. But again, what's the issue? Is the chart don't rendered at all? What exactly isn't working as expected? It will be **much** easier if you can create a working example with the data in tools such as https://jsbin.com/, https://jsfiddle.net/ etc.

Comment: @MoshFeu I have also added the Current (actual) result which will give you an idea. I'm getting a single line rather than multiple lines. Each `TagsN` Supposed to be Lines and not just altogether as 1 line. the result that I want is also on the question.

Comment: I think I've a better picture now. According the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html), if you want to display multiple lines `datasets` array should has item for each chart. In your code, the array has only one item. I believe that you need to split the array "group by" `tagsN` so you'll have 4 groups in array which you'll pass as `datasets`.

Comment: yes Mosh, I see you getting a picture. However, the data can change automatically and the `TagsN` can also change from the database. That why I want if possible a way to display a multiple lines chart without hardcode the Dataset. `TagsN` Must be free of changing. do you have an answer to that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224137/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-patsonleaner).

Comment: @MoshFeu I have added a Jsfiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/opcd1g8w/4/

Comment: The data is not consistent (13 items in `data`, 17 items in `labels`) but here is a start - https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/t3o0bvz2/31/ (read the first comment for further explanation.

Comment: @MoshFeu, you are a Genius, I spent days to solve that but your answer was sufficient, that's what I am looking for. Would you please post it so I can select it as the best answer for this question. Thanks a millions

Comment: Thank you :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.datasets` accepts an array so each item in the array will add another line to the chart.

Here are the steps to "convert" the data from the database to the chart's format:

- Use `SerializeObject` to serilize the table into JSON. It should look something like

```json
[
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Escalation", TagsD: "06 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 7, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "06 Oct" },
]
```

- Group the records by their `TagsN` prop (You can do this also in the [database itself](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) which is recommended in large data sets). [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can help to do it in a clean way so the outcome is a Map - the keys are the `TagsN`s and the values are a list of items which have this `TagsN`.

```js
[[Entries]]
0: {"Escalation" => Array(1)}
1: {"Switchboard In" => Array(7)}
2: {"Account Manager" => Array(5)}
...
```

- Convert this to chartjs `datasets` format.

```
0: {label: "Escalation", data: Array(1)}
1: {label: "Switchboard In", data: Array(7)}
2: data: (5) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
   label: "Account Manager"
```

Working example:

```js
// this data should come from the server
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
const grouped = groupBy(data, 'TagsN');
const lineData = {
  datasets: Array.from(grouped).map(([key, items], index) => ({
    label: key,
    data: items.map(item => item.TagsC),
    backgroundColor: colors[index]
  })),
  labels: Array.from(new Set([...TagsDs]))
};

new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart").getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: lineData,
  fill: false
});

function groupBy(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, current) => {
    const groupKey = current[key];
    if (!prev.has(groupKey)) {
      prev.set(groupKey, []);
    }
    prev.get(groupKey).push(current);
    return prev;
  }, new Map());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="250"></canvas>

<script>
const TagsDs = ["06 Oct","06 Oct","07 Oct","08 Oct","08 Oct","09 Oct","12 Oct","12 Oct","12 Oct","13 Oct","13 Oct","14 Oct","14 Oct","14 Oct","14 Oct"];
const data = [
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Escalation", TagsD: "06 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 7, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "06 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 3, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "07 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Account Manager", TagsD: "08 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 10, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "08 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 4, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "09 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Account Manager", TagsD: "12 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Account Manager", TagsD: "12 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 6, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "12 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Account Manager", TagsD: "13 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 10, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "13 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 1, TagsN: "Account Manager", TagsD: "14 Oct" },
  { TagsC: 6, TagsN: "Switchboard In", TagsD: "14 Oct" },
];
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/t3o0bvz2/38/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, I see that time spent with you paid off well and gladly I learn about new things too. :).